# What is the best data structure to perform the following queries and why am I getting wrong result in mine

Tags: c, stack, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I need to build a data structure that:

1. learn x (insert x)
2. forget x (deletes x). if x not present, do nothing
3. decrease x n - decreases the count of x by n, if n >= count, then the node is simply deleted. and if x not present then do nothing
4. smaller_nums x - find number of nodes(counting their multiplicity) that are less than x
5. larger_nums x - similar to 4. but larger
6. asc k - print k'th element in ascending order(counting multiplicity), print -1 if k > total number of nodes

1≤ q ≤ 5*10^5

1≤ x ≤ 10^9

I have built an AVL tree for this, is there any better and simple data structure for this?

My code is working fine for the given input and output:

```
Input:
14
learn 5
learn 2
learn 7
learn 3
learn 2
smaller_nums 5 
larger_nums 2 
asc 2
decrease 2 1 
asc 2
forget 7 
larger_nums 2 
forget 5 
larger_nums 2
Output: 
3
3
2
3 
2
1
```

When I am submitting, I am passing 4/9 test cases.
I am getting wrong answer for 2 test cases and timeout for 3 testcases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long int N=0; //keeps count of total number nodes, this value is used in asc function only
// An AVL tree node
struct node {
    long int key;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    long int height;
    long int count;
};

// A utility function to get height of the tree
long int height(struct node* N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return N->height;
}

// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
long int max(long int a, long int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
    NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(long int key)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
        malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->height = 1; // new node is initially added at leaf
    node->count = 1;
    return (node);
}

// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct node* rightRotate(struct node* y)
{
    struct node* x = y->left;
    struct node* T2 = x->right;

    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    // Update heights
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return x;
}

// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct node* leftRotate(struct node* x)
{
    struct node* y = x->right;
    struct node* T2 = y->left;

    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    // Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    // Return new root
    return y;
}

// Get Balance factor of node N
long int getBalance(struct node* N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, long int key)
{
    /* 1. Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (node == NULL)
    {   N++;
        return (newNode(key));
    }
    // If key already exists in BST, increment count and return
    if (key == node->key) {
        (node->count)++;
        N++;
        return node;
    }

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left = insert(node->left, key);
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = max(height(node->left), height(node->right)) + 1;

    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor node to check whether
    this node became unbalanced */
    long int balance = getBalance(node);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
        return rightRotate(node);

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
        return leftRotate(node);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key) {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key) {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

/* Given a non-empty binary search tree, return the node with minimum
key value found in that tree. Note that the entire tree does not
need to be searched. */
struct node* minValueNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;

    /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}
struct node* forgetNode(struct node* root, long int key)
{
    // STEP 1: PERFORM STANDARD BST DELETE

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
    // then it lies in left subtree
    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = forgetNode(root->left, key);

    // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
    // then it lies in right subtree
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = forgetNode(root->right, key);

    // if key is same as root's key, then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else {
        N += -(root->count);
        // If key is present more than once, simply decrement
        // count and return
        // Else, delete the node

        // node with only one child or no child
        if ((root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL)) {
            struct node* temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            // No child case
            if (temp == NULL) {
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else // One child case
                *root = *temp; // Copy the contents of the non-empty child

            free(temp);
        }
        else {
            // node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
            // in the right subtree)
            struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

            // Copy the inorder successor's data to this node and update the count
            root->key = temp->key;
            root->count = temp->count;
            temp->count = 1;

            // Delete the inorder successor
            root->right = forgetNode(root->right, temp->key);
        }
    }

    // If the tree had only one node then return
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    // STEP 2: UPDATE HEIGHT OF THE CURRENT NODE
    root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;

    // STEP 3: GET THE BALANCE FACTOR OF THIS NODE (to check whether
    // this node became unbalanced)
    long int balance = getBalance(root);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) >= 0)
        return rightRotate(root);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) < 0) {
        root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
        return rightRotate(root);
    }

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) <= 0)
        return leftRotate(root);

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) > 0) {
        root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
        return leftRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node* decreaseNode(struct node* root, long int key, long int n)
{
    // STEP 1: PERFORM STANDARD BST DELETE

    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
    // then it lies in left subtree
    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = decreaseNode(root->left, key, n);

    // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
    // then it lies in right subtree
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = decreaseNode(root->right, key, n);

    // if key is same as root's key, then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else {

        // If key is present more than once, simply decrement
        // count and return
        if (root->count > 1 && n < root->count) {
            (root->count) += -n;
            N += -n;
            return root;
        }
        // Else, delete the node

        // node with only one child or no child
        N += -(root->count);
        if ((root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL)) {
            struct node* temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            // No child case
            if (temp == NULL) {
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else // One child case
                *root = *temp; // Copy the contents of the non-empty child

            free(temp);
        }
        else {
            // node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
            // in the right subtree)
            struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

            // Copy the inorder successor's data to this node and update the count
            root->key = temp->key;
            root->count = temp->count;
            temp->count = 1;

            // Delete the inorder successor
            root->right = decreaseNode(root->right, temp->key, n);
        }
    }

    // If the tree had only one node then return
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    // STEP 2: UPDATE HEIGHT OF THE CURRENT NODE
    root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;

    // STEP 3: GET THE BALANCE FACTOR OF THIS NODE (to check whether
    // this node became unbalanced)
    long int balance = getBalance(root);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) >= 0)
        return rightRotate(root);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) < 0) {
        root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
        return rightRotate(root);
    }

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) <= 0)
        return leftRotate(root);

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) > 0) {
        root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
        return leftRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}
// Convinience function to travers the tree in ascending order
void inOrder(struct node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        printf("%ld(%ld) ", root->key, root->count);
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}
// Find out number of larger nodes
void largerNums(struct node* root, long int key, long int* lnums){
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    if (key < root->key){
        (*lnums) += root->count;
        largerNums(root->right, key, lnums);
        largerNums(root->left, key, lnums);
    }
    else if (key >= root->key)
        largerNums(root->right, key, lnums);

    return;
}
// Find out number of smaller nodes
void smallerNums(struct node* root, long int key, long int* snums){
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    if (key <= root->key){
        smallerNums(root->left, key, snums);
    }
    else if (key > root->key){
        (*snums) += root->count;
        smallerNums(root->left, key, snums);
        smallerNums(root->right, key, snums);
    }
    return;

}
// Prints k'th element in ascending order
void asc(struct node* root, long int key, long int* cnt){

    if (root != NULL) {
        asc(root->left, key, cnt);
        int i;
        for(i=1; i <= (root->count); ++i){
            (*cnt)++;
            if(*cnt == key){
                printf("%ld\n", root->key);
                return;
            }
        }
        asc(root->right, key, cnt);
    }

}
// Function to compare strings
int myStrCompare(char a[], char b[]){
   int c = 0;

   while (a[c] == b[c]) {
      if (a[c] == '\0' || b[c] == '\0')
         break;
      c++;
   }

   if (a[c] == '\0' && b[c] == '\0')
      return 0;
   else
      return -1;
}
// Function to know what command entered by user
int myCompare(char *str){

    if(myStrCompare(str, "learn") == 0)
        return 1;
    else if(myStrCompare(str, "forget") == 0)
        return 2;
    else if(myStrCompare(str, "decrease") == 0)
        return 3;
    else if(myStrCompare(str, "smaller_nums") == 0)
        return 4;
    else if(myStrCompare(str, "larger_nums") == 0)
        return 5;
    else if(myStrCompare(str, "asc") == 0)
        return 6;

    return -1;
}

/* Driver program to test above function*/
int main()
{
    long int i, q, x, n, lnums, snums, cnt;
    int choice;
    char input[100];
    struct node* root= NULL;

    scanf("%ld", &q);
    //printf("%s", input);

    for(i=1; i<=q; ++i){
        scanf("%s", input);
        //printf("%s", input);
        choice = myCompare(input);
        //printf("\n%d", choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1: scanf("%ld", &x);
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                root = insert(root, x);
               /* printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                break;
            case 2: scanf("%ld", &x);
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                root = forgetNode(root, x);
                /*printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                break;
            case 3: scanf("%ld%ld", &x, &n);
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                if(n < 1){
                    break;
                }else{
                    root = decreaseNode(root, x, n);
                }
               /* printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                break;
            case 4: scanf("%ld", &x);
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                snums = 0;
                smallerNums(root, x, &snums);
                /*printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                printf("%ld\n", snums);
                break;
            case 5: scanf("%ld", &x);
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                lnums = 0;
                largerNums(root, x, &lnums);
                /*printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                printf("%ld\n", lnums);
                break;
            case 6: scanf("%ld", &x);
                if(x > N){
                    printf("%d\n", -1);
                    break;
                }else{
                //printf("\nEntered x\n: %d", x);
                    cnt=0;
                    asc(root, x, &cnt);
                }
                /*printf("\n");
                inOrder(root);
                printf("\n");*/
                break;

        }
    }
    /*root = insert(root, 5);
    root = insert(root, 2);
    root = insert(root, 7);
    root = insert(root, 3);
    root = insert(root, 2);
    smallerNums(root, 5, &s);
    printf("\n%d\n", s);
    largerNums(root, 2, &l);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    inOrderK(root, 2, &cnt); cnt = 0;
    root = decreaseNode(root, 2, 1);
    inOrderK(root, 2, &cnt); cnt = 0;
    root = forgetNode(root, 7);
    l=0;
    largerNums(root, 2, &l);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    root = forgetNode(root, 5);
    l=0;
    largerNums(root, 2, &l);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    inOrder(root);
    l=0;
    largerNums(root, 1, &l);
    printf("\n%d\n", l);
    */


    return 0;
}
```

I have looked over my code multiple times and unable to figure out what is wrong

Comment: AVL is fine, so are any of the other balanced tree choices. A wrong answer is just that. If you are doing this for a coding site like hackerrank, etc.., know the test cases will test all corner-cases. Empty tree, tree with all 10^9 values, etc... and asking for all sets of data (greater than, less than, etc.). Do you have the input for the case that is wrong? The timeouts are likely due to a logic error causing your code to loop endlessly or something similar. If you have the data for your failed case, please add that to your question. May need to spend some hackos...

Comment: The test cases I don’t think I can buy them

Comment: Have you compiled your code with the `-Wshadow` option and then looked at lines `3, 14 & 80`? The variable `N` will be problematic both as a global `int` and as a pointer `struct node* N`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin tried running it after changing, still failing the same test cases and getting TLE

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in log(n) time 
Put left_count and right_count in node

Comment: I have  thought about that already but have no idea how to update those left and right count when a node with multiplicity > 1 is removed from the tree. Can you teach me